# How to increase display timeout in asp.net label control tooltip

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, tooltip, controls

I have a label control on my ASP>NET page and its tool tip values are set at run time.

Do we have a way to increase the tool tip timeout ?

Comment: show your existing code.. you can create a new instance at runtime and use the overloads that come when creating a new instance of ToolTip
so when you call `tooltip.Show("1st parm, 2nd Param, 3rd param)` the 3rd param being an integer value that would control how long the tooltip stays open.. meaning set a new `delay` time also there are several examples of this on Google.. I am looking at one now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The tooltip (html title attribute) by default is a function of the browser and is not controllable.

you can use custom:

[jQuery Custom ToolTips](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-custom-tooltips)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as it is a function of the browser,but what you can try is using jQueryUI js

An example of controlling the duration on the show property:

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({ show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 } });
```